# SQL - Add id to all rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's assume my table is the following:

```
id | name | country
--------------------
   | John | USA
   | Mary | USA
   | Mike | USA
```

Someone can help me with a script that can add id's to all names?

Thanks

Comment: Simplest option is to use cursor and update each row.

Comment: from where you are getting id ? is it random or auto incremented ?

Comment: @PareshJadhav while a cursor may *seem* to be an easy  solution, it does not scale well to a large table. Databases do not generally work well with loops and a set-based operation like the ones suggested in the answers will perform *much* better on non-trivial table sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- Create a temporary table for the example.
CREATE TABLE #People(Id int, Name nvarchar(10), Country nvarchar(10))

-- Insert data, leaving the Id column NULL.
INSERT INTO #People(Name, Country) SELECT
    'John', 'USA' UNION ALL SELECT
    'Mary', 'USA' UNION ALL SELECT
    'Mike', 'USA';

-- 1. Use Row_Number() to generate an Id.
-- 2. Wrap the query in a common table expression (CTE), which is like an inline view.
-- 3. If the CTE references a single table, we can update the CTE to affect the underlying table.
WITH PeopleCte AS (
    SELECT 
        Id, 
        Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NewId 
    FROM 
        #People    
)
UPDATE PeopleCte SET Id = NewId

SELECT * FROM #People

DROP TABLE #People
```

Comment: Is the base table PEOPLE? and shouldn't it be Select From base table after updation?

Comment: I've updated with comments to clarify. People (now PeopleCte) is a common table expression. You can generate the ID and perform the update in a single query this way. #sqlservermagic

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
update table set a.id=b.newid from  table a,(select row_number() over (order by (select null)) newid,name from #temp) b
```

make changes like ordering as needed